# Using an EditorPart inside a Composite

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm new to RCP and I'm trying to create a new View or Editor. At the current state I'm extending `ViewPart`.

The Layout I want to achieve is a `SashForm` where both sides have a `CTabFolder`. One of the sides of the `SashForm` is basically a `MultiPageEditorPart`. One of it's tabs should be an editor for a specific language with syntax highlighting and similar features. From what I understand I could extend `AbstractTextEditor` for that (and maybe use it as one tab of a `MultiPageEditorPart`).

If I try to achieve this layout with a `ViewPart` as top level container which contains a `SashForm`, I can't add an `EditorPart` to one of the sides of the `SashForm`. Of course I could implement this editor from scratch as `Composite` but I want to avoid that.

I am also willing to use an `EditorPart` or `MultiPageEditorPart` as top level container but then I'd have to find a way to get the `SashForm` layout working. The whole editor should be splited first and then each side should have tabs.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

If anything is unclear please ask. I've got the feeling I've put this into words a little complicatedly.

Comment: What's driving your decision to glue the two main "sides" of your view together with the `SashForm`?  I'm sure you've got a reason, but maybe you could talk yourself out of it?  Given the complexities you're buying I wonder if you might be better off letting each of those two sides live in their own `ViewPart`.  One could be a `MultiPageEditorPart` and the other the `CTabFolder`.  This would give your users more freedom in positioning the two pieces on their screens as well.

Comment: I thought about that. The view is a search interface. One of the sides is for query formulation the other for results. This way I want to support the cyclic process of result validation and query refinement by the user. If I split it into two views it might work with one open search at a time. With more than one (which is a requirement) the user would have a hard time assigning a result view to it's query.

Comment: Keeping those two pieces glued together sounds like a good idea.  I think you should just make a `ViewPart` that has a text editing component of some kind on the left, instead of an `EditorPart`.  All that `EditorPart` is really buying you is dirty flag management and Save support; syntax highlight and so forth you can get from a variety of different text controls out there.

Comment: That was what I was thinking too until I stumbled upon my problem. Can you recommend a control that does what I'm looking for? Ideally it should support syntax and error highlighting as well as auto completion the way e.g. the default Java editor does. Also feel free to post this as an answer instead of a comment so I can give you some rep and maybe accept it later on :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just make a `ViewPart` that has a text editing component of some kind on the left, instead of trying to find a way to use an `EditorPart`. All that `EditorPart` is really buying you is dirty flag management and Save support; syntax highlight and so forth you can add to the text editing component yourself (I was surprised at how few drop-in text components I found while poking around the internet just now; I expected to find "a few" and instead I found "basically none").

You can see one way to do very rudimentary syntax highlighting with a `StyledText` component here: [JavaSourceCodeViewer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JavaSourcecodeViewer.htm)

To see a more robust implementation of things like syntax highlight and autocomplete, take a look at the class that Eclipse uses for the editing of Java source code: `CompilationUnitEditor`

Comment: First prototype works fine with syntax highlighting. If I also get auto completion working this will be the solution in favour.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is quite complicated and might require a lot of extra work. See an editor is not just different controls laid out in some order, but it has a lot of additional features that any editor class expects to work. These include things like selection service and action bars etc, that you will need to hook in to ensure smooth running.

That said, it should be possible to achieve what you are hoping for. You can have a look at the source code of the `MultiPageEditorPart` itself to see how it converts a single editor into a multi page editor, which is capable of hosting a completely independent editor on each of its pages. You would need to achieve something similar if you want your editor to host two `MultiPageEditorPart`s separated by a sash. If you want to carry on, you should start implementing some stuff and if you run into any problems, post them here. You would be able to get a lot better help then.

Comment: I appreciate your input. It will take some time to look into it. If it works and no one comes up with something easier I will accept your answer.

Comment: Here is how I envision implementing this. You extend the `MultiPageEditorPart` because apart from the fact that you will have pages divided by sash, your editor still has multiple pages. The sash part is only visual and you can consider that an implementation technicality. This way you will not have to implement a lot of editor specific glue.

Comment: In your extension of `MultiPageEditorPart` you can override `addPage` methods and use the page instance to determine which side of the sash they need to be on. Also override `createPageContainer` to create parent for the entire editor that has a sash, and a tab folder on each sash. Similar approach should also be doable for a `FormEditor`.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like MultiPageEditorSite. Use it for inspiration when implementing an EditorSiteDelegate. MultiPageEditorSite has support for separate keybindings between the pages, for example.

```
class ChildEditorSite implements IEditorSite {
    IEditorSite parent;
    public Object method() {
       return parent.method();
    }
}
```

Using this class, you can easily do the following in your main EditorPart:

```
class MyCoolPart extends EditorPart {
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
         EditorPart child1 = new MyChild();
         child1.init(new ChildEditorSite(getEditorSite()), myInput);
         EditorPart child2 = new MyChild();
         child2.init(new ChildEditorSite(getEditorSite()), myInput);

         child1.createPartControl(parent);
         child2.createPartControl(parent);
    }
}
```

Be sure to also dispose of your children correctly when you dispose of your MyCoolPart. Please note that this only works in the most basic of cases. An EditorPart that is a DocumentEditor or that relies on IPersistablePart or implements listeners/adapters for confirming a save is probably going to require a lot more Lifecycle management...